# Quinoa flour rusks

Tags: substitutions

My daughter struggles with food intolerance issues. 
How do I substitute the flour in this recipe (link below) for :
- Quinoa flour
- Almond flour
- Combination of both?

http://thehungryherbivore.com/south-african-vegan-rusk-recipe/
Thank you ♡

Comment: Have you tried a one to one swap? If so, what happened?

Answer (score 2):

[According to one vegan South African cook](https://www.aninas-recipes.com/recipes/vegan-nut-and-seed-rusks/), you can indeed make rusks with almond flour.  I'd suggest using her recipe instead of substituting into the one you linked; it's really hard to get moisture balance right with gluten-free baking.